# Tomcat Authentication and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

I downloaded JavaMelody (server statistics) and applied it to my Spring project. Everything works just fine with this one - after inserting `http://myAplication/monitoring` I can see  JavaMelody page. I decided, that this should be protected by password. So I followed documentation and added in `tomcat-users.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="monitoring" />
    <user username="monitoring" password="monitoring" roles="monitoring" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Then I inserted some lines into `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- JAVA MELODY MONITOR ACCESS -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Monitoring</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>monitoring</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Monitoring</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/monitoring</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>monitoring</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Now when I type `http://myAplication/monitoring` I get authentication popup - that's cool. But when I enter credentials and click ok, another authentication popup shows. Difference is, that this one is from Spring Security (I haven't seen that popup anywhere in my app).

[image]
[image]

And now, I enter credentials for Spring Security (other credentials) and JavaMelody page starts to show, but ANOTHER **monitoring** popup shows, and then **spring security**, and again, and again... - until all page elements are loaded.

My Spring Security conf

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-page='/' default-target-url='/login_ok'
        always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/login_failed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>
```

Is there a way to make Spring Security and Tomcat Authentication work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decide what you want: Container Manager Security (`web.xml`) or Spring Security (`beans.xml`). You should not use both. That's why you see two Basic realm names.

Comment: I see. Thanks for info, I have to deal with this :)

Comment: @Michael-O How can I add `<http-basic />` to spring security config to use basic authentication before normal form login?

Comment: You can supply and precendence/order attribute. It is well defined and can be looked up in the official [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-stack).

Answer (score 0):

There used to be Container Adapter Authentication in Spring Security 2.x -- it was an "Adapter to enable Catalina (Tomcat) to authenticate via the Spring Security."

Not sure if this functionality exists in Spring Security 3.x or 4.x