# Spring security: basic authentication before form login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to add (temporary for demo) basic authentication before website is shown. So user can enter some credentials like `demo/demo` to open website and after that to use normal `form-login` authentication.
I try to add this `http` before normal form login.

```
<http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="basicAuthManager">
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />  
   <http-basic />
</http>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
...
<form-login .../>
</http>
```

But I have exception:

```
A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain,  
causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http>
namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

It seems I cannot use `pattern="/**"` twice?
Is it possible to do what I want?
Also I do not need to set principal in the security context after successful basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for Spring to accept multiple authentication schemes. However as far as I know it is not possible to require double authentication (e.g. login with BASIC and with FORM at the same time). So it is not possible to do what you want.

The easiest solution for you would be to define the BASIC authentication in your servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) or in front of the servlet container in a proxy HTTP server (e.g. Apache or Nginx).

It is somewhat a good practice to have HTTP server in front of servlet container, so I would go for the second option.

---

If you still feel like hacking the BASIC auth inside your applicaiton, you can easily write your own authentication servlet filter. That should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: This is how I started with but I had exactly the same problems as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198729/tomcat-authentication-and-spring-security

Comment: Issue with that question is that `auto-config` was used. This automatically registers `http-basic` processing components. So both Tomcat and Spring Security were trying to interpret `Authorization` header. Please refer to the [official documentation of that feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auto-config).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems here:

1. You have two `http` tags. I am not 100% sure but I have a strong suspicion this is not right
2. You do not need the pattern in the `http` tag. Give it a try after removing it and leaving just the `pattern` property at the `intercept-url` level. Additionally, since you will not be manipulating the `Principal` you will need to use `isAuthenticated()` rather than `hasRole(...)`. Like this:

   ```
   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="basicAuthManager">
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />  
      <http-basic />
   </http>
   ```